# GPT3 completion with insertion - invalid argument :suffix

Tags: openai-api, gpt-3

I am trying out completions using insertions.

It seems that I am supposed to use a parameter called `suffix:` to inform where the end of the insert goes.

[image]

### The payload to the endpoint: `POST /v1/completions`

```json
{
  "model": "code-davinci-002",
  "prompt": "Write a JSON document for a person with first name, last name, email and phone number\n\n{\n",
  "suffix": "\n}",
  "temperature": 0,
  "max_tokens": 256,
  "top_p": 1,
  "frequency_penalty": 0,
  "presence_penalty": 0
}
```

I tried doing this from a ruby implementation of GPT3.

```rb
parameters
=> {
:model=>"code-davinci-001",
 :prompt=>"generate some JSON for a person with first and last name {",
 :max_tokens=>250,
 :temperature=>0,
 :top_p=>1,
 :frequency_penalty=>0,
 :presence_penalty=>0,
 :suffix=>"\n}"}
```

```rb
post(url: "/v1/completions", parameters: parameters)
```

I get an invalid argument error for `suffix`

```rb
{"error"=>{"message"=>"Unrecognized request argument supplied: suffix", "type"=>"invalid_request_error", "param"=>nil, "code"=>nil}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked at the Payload from OpenAI vs the payload from the Ruby Library and saw the issue.

My ruby library was setting the model to `code-davinci-001` while OpenAI was using `code-davinci-002`.

As soon as I manually altered the model: attribute in debug, the completion started working correctly.

```json
{
  "id"=>"cmpl-5yJ8b01Cw26W6ZIHoRSOb71Dc4QvH",
  "object"=>"text_completion",
  "created"=>1665054929,
  "model"=>"code-davinci-002",
  "choices"=>
  [{"text"=>"\n    \"firstName\": \"John\",\n    \"lastName\": \"Smith\"",
    "index"=>0,
    "logprobs"=>nil,
    "finish_reason"=>"stop"}],
  "usage"=>{"prompt_tokens"=>14, "completion_tokens"=>19, 
 "total_tokens"=>33}
}
```